# Career mode Sponsorship explanation for FIFA 13

Tags: fifa-13

I'm really enjoying FIFA 13 Career mode, but am confused by how the sponsorship work.

Could somebody help clarify?

I think I figured out most of it but...

- **Funding per game**: this seems clear
- **Loyalty bonus**: do I get this if I choose again the same sponsor from previous year? What if I don't remember who it was?
- **League Bonus**: is this for WINNING the league?
- **Domestic Cup Bonus**: I guess this is for winning the domestic cup?
- **International Cup Bonus**: same as above
- **Extra Bonus**: as described

I even downloaded the manual but there's nothing in it!

Comment: There are sponsors in Fifa 13 career mode? I have never seen this? I only really do Manager mode though, is this a Player mode thing?

Comment: yes it's a single-player mode. when you play in career mode, every year you get to choose your team's sponsor...

Answer (score 1):

All cup bonuses are for the matches in the cups or tournaments. The league bonus is for the end of the league or if you win the season.

Answer (score 0):

- **Funding per game**: this is awarded for every match, even friendly ones at the beginning of the season!
- **Loyalty Bonus**: ?
- **League Bonus**: ?
- **Domestic Cup Bonus**: ?
- **International Cup Bonus**: ?
- **Extra Bonus**: variable

Comment: During my findings I will update this answer, if somebody comes up with the full answer first I'll happily reward him!

Comment: I finished one season... and still am unsure about what I got :-/ I'll try to be more precise for the next season..